# PHP: display meta description for a few html's

Tags: php, html, meta

I'm stuck on a code to display meta descriptions for more then one html pages.

this code displays three time the same meta description, I want 2 display 3 different meta's.  What do I wrong?

```html
$kfamily = is_page(683);
  if ($kfamily && get_children(93518)):
$html = file_get_contents_curl("https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$URL['PATH']."/kenfam_00/");
  endif;
  if ($kfamily && get_children(93520)):
$html = file_get_contents_curl("https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$URL['PATH']."/kenfam_01/");
  endif;
 if ($kfamily && get_children(93522)):
$html = file_get_contents_curl("https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$URL['PATH']."/kenfam_02/");
 endif;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);

    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

$list_pages_html .= '<div class="description-meta">'.$description.'</div>';
```

Comment: Try test if $kfamily is true i.e. if( $kfamily==true && ....

Comment: I have tested it: "$kfamily == true &&..." it's the same problem as before. He displays the same meta descriptions for all meta descriptions. I have been testing with arrays, but it's the same problem. I don't understand it, the url's are different to eachother and I'm sure that every meta descriptions is different.

Comment: Is there a way to load multiple html's =>  @$doc->loadHTML($html[0],$html[1],$html[2]);???

Comment: by the way: he displays the last meta description of "kenfam_02" x 3. Maybe there is another option for the if function...???

Comment: Okéy, I have another solution for this problem, I don't need the meta description anymore and no more difficult php codes. The same thing you can do is with excerpt. Just include the next code in your theme: [add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );] and then you get the excerpt database and you can change it many times you want, I think is the best solution in that case. The excerpt database can you find in phpmyadmin => yourdatabasename_posts -> post_excerpt.